# Taking Ibrahim (Abrahim) as friend

Tags: quran, tafseer

Allah (swt) in Surah Nisa Ayah 125 says:

> وَمَنْ أَحْسَنُ دِينًۭا مِّمَّنْ أَسْلَمَ وَجْهَهُۥ لِلَّهِ وَهُوَ مُحْسِنٌۭ وَٱتَّبَعَ مِلَّةَ إِبْرَٰهِيمَ حَنِيفًۭا ۗ وَٱتَّخَذَ ٱللَّهُ إِبْرَٰهِيمَ خَلِيلًۭا

Is this not against him being Subhan?

In other places Allah condemns those people who claim that Allah has children and immediately says that he is Subhan and free from needing children.

I can't reconcile friendship with being Subhan.

Comment: خليل doesn't exclusively mean (close) friend and in this context it is rather a gift or maybe a status Allah has given Ibraheem. So it isn't something Allah is in need of and therefore there shouldn't be a conflict here. However it is worth investigating to hopefully understand the last part of the verse better.

Comment: The difference between children and friends should be obvious.

Comment: @TheZ of course it's not obvious. Both mean "need". A rock never gets a friend, because it does not need it.

Comment: Not sure where you got need. Rocks don't get friends because they can't and don't want it. Want is not the same as need.

Comment: @TheZ, it seems that to want is not like to need. But drop your friends for a couple of years, and the melancholy of loneliness would turn your want into a need.

Comment: Ok, but not sure why you're comparing humans to God. Who told you God's wishes turn into needs other than trying to compare to humans?

Comment: @TheZ I'm not comparing. I want to understand. I want to be able to defend my religion and my belief. A lot of false gods have families and relatives in pantheons and they fight and they become jealous, etc. But I chose Islam (again) because of the extreme uniqueness of Allah that can not be compared at all to other false deities. Yet when I read this verse or verses related to *helping Allah* I feel extremely bad.